# Python private class attribute returning different value than its getter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm playing with a private class attribute that has a public getter

```
class MyClass:
    __val = 0

    def __init__(self):
        MyClass.__val += 1

    @classmethod
    def get_val(cls):
        return MyClass.__val

    def set_val(self):
        MyClass.__val += 1
        return


MyClass.__val = -1
print('Accessing attribute directly:', MyClass.__val)
print('Accessing attribute via getter:', MyClass.get_val())
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Accessing attribute directly: -1
Accessing attribute via getter: 0
```

How is it I have two objects with different `.__val` values from this code?

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed public, the class attributes are bound to the class, and the class has only one. SO the instantiated object will get a common value

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you didn't instatiate the class. Then, when you use the get_val() method, it doesn't call the __init__ method to initialize the __val.
Otherwhise, if you instantiate MyClass it will keep the value defined in the **init** method. But `MyClass.__val` will still show -1 because it is an class attribute and not a instance attribute like the one defined inside the **init**.

```
MyClass.__val = -1
m = MyClass()
print('Accessing attribute directly:', MyClass.__val)
print('Accessing attribute via getter:', MyClass.get_val())
```

[image]

Comment: But I (purposefully) haven't instantiated the class, so why are there two different values on the same attribute?

Comment: This is just not correct. The `__init__` assigns to a class variable, not an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't two objects. There's *one* object with *two different attributes*:

```
MyClass._MyClass__val
```

And

```
MyClass.__val
```

This is because assigning to `__val` **outside the class definition** bypasses the machinery that does the name-mangling. So:

```
MyClass.__val = -1
```

create *another variable*. Essentially, name-mangling only occurs *in methods that are compiled as part of the class definition*, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores,
>   at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, **as long as it occurs
>   within the definition of a class**.

Comment: Why is the interpreter allowing me to assign to ```MyClass.__val``` at all if it's a private attribute? Why would I be allowed to create new attributes on the fly after the class has been defined?

Comment: @BBrooklyn it's not private. Python *doesn't have private variables*. This is double-underscore name-mangling, which is to prevent name-collisions in subclasses. And you are *always* allowed to assign attributes to an object, unless that object explicitly prevents you.

Comment: What is the purpose of double underscore then?

Comment: @BBrooklyn to prevent name collisions in subclasses. To make a variable "private", a *single* underscore should be used (of course, this is a *convention*)

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct about collisions. A class definition creates a new namespace so there are no attributes to collide with.

Comment: @BBrooklyn then tell the Python developers and the authors of the documentation that: "Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling."  But **of course** attributes will collide. If I create a `Base` class with a `.foo` attribute, and a `Sub` class with the same `.foo` attribute, then it will *collide with the parent class attribute*. Of *course* the namespaces are distinct, *but inheritance **is** the sharing of namespaces*